# particle system not evenly emitting particles on faces destpite clean topology

Tags: particles, topology

i am trying to figure out why the particles are not emitting evenly across the surface to avoid the issue in future.
No vertices are un-merged nor are any faces flipped.
But the emitter somehow groups the particles on two faces less then on the others.
Does anybody have a suggestion on how to trouble shoot this further or where it could come from?[image]

Comment: I was only able to fix it with a new mesh. Maybe somebody has an idea how to profile the issue?

Comment: hello; hard to say without the file